# How do I run "php phpunit.phar" CLI from anywhere?

Tags: php, phpunit, command-line-interface

I just installed phpunit.phar and am trying to set it up.  What I am trying to do is to put phpunit.phar in a path so that I can run it from anywhere directly from the php cli.  At this point, it is in my include_path and I can include it within a script from anywhere.  But, what I think I need to do is run it from the cli "php phpunit.phar".

Is this doable or is it even appropriate?

Comment: Trying to figure out a work-around would leave your server open to attack.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHAR's in general.  Should the PHAR itself be installed so that phpunit is a standalone CLI?  If so, how would I do that?  Thanks...

Comment: I should mention that this "server" is a standalone development laptop.  I don't expect to run the same configuration in a production server.

Comment: If it's not in /htdocs(or /html or /httpdocs) there's a reason...

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm sorry, I am a little bit confused about /htdocs roll in a CLI environment.  Can you help me?  Thanks.

Comment: What are you running? Linux? If so, which distribution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that the phpunit.phar just need to be in your path variable. Or write a small script which is located in /usr/bin with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
php /path/to/phpunit.phar
```

Comment: The batch script worked fine, and thanks for your help.  I was looking for a solution that was more general, but this certainly helped me and solve the problem.  Thanks so much...RG

Comment: How to find this path? I use `whereis phpunit` and obtain: `/usr/local/bin/phpunit`. Is this the same like `phpunit` with exension `phar`?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using windows

1. create bat file named phpunit.bat
2. past the below line
3. keep the file any where you want
4. set the path variable on windows

> ```
> %~dp0php.exe %~dp0pharcommand.phar %*
> ```

Now you can run on cmd prompt

```
phpunit --v
```

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer necesssary, according to http://phpunit.de/getting-started.html. You can simply rename phpunit.phar to phpunit, chmod it executable, and put it in your path (usually /usr/local/bin) and it should automatically detect the interpreter directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it from everywhere. Just give the correct path:

```
/usr/share/pear/exec/phpunit.phar -c app
```